# In Chrome, why does sorting a longer array flip entries when the sort is ran multiple times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, v8

**EDIT**
This issue seems to only happen in Chrome.

---

I am sorting an array of objects containing information about people. The sort is based on the last name (ascending).

There are 44 objects in the array, and a few people in the array have last names that match.

How I am currently sorting:

```
people.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.last_name.localeCompare(b.last_name);
});
```

When sorting the array multiple times it results in some people with the same last name being swapped or reorganized.

However, when I remove the last object in the array, and rerun the simulation, this resorting stops happening in at least one place.

If I remove even more random objects (but not the ones with the same last name) then all stop reorganizing on multiple resorts.

I thought it might be the `localeCompare()` function, but I tried the following code which still has the same issue.

```
people.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.last_name < b.last_name) return -1;
    if(a.last_name > b.last_name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

This must have something to do with how the method `sort()` is built and what it does when there are larger arrays.

Here is a JSFiddle with instructions on how to replicate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/kevbot/kro30wy0/

How can I stop this reorganization of data when performing multiple resorts?

*Note: I realize it is silly to resort arrays that don't change more than once. But... this example is a base example. The actual implementation will have more people objects added dynamically and will need to be resorted each time.*

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
a sorting algorithm doesn't have to be stable. It can't be an issue of Chrome.

Comment: Right, the EcmaScript specification does not require sort to be stable, especially since stable sorting algorithms are somewhat slower.

Comment: That is interesting. That has never stood out to me. I guess the initial confusion has come from each other browser was stable and therefore it causes an assumption that it is a bug in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens because of the way sorting works. If you want to always have the same order for the ones that match (localcompare gives 0), you need to give an additional order for those. This is an example using ids:

```
people.sort(function (a, b) {
    var compare = a.last_name.localeCompare(b.last_name);
    if(compare == 0) return a.id < b.id
    return compare
});
```

If instead of returning `a.id < b.id` you do a `console.log(a,b)` you will notice that for 2 persons with the same last name, in one loop a = firstPerson, b = secondPerson but on the second loop, a = secondPeron and b = firstPerson, in those cases they get swapped on the sort

Comment: I do my development in Chrome and realized after posting this that it seems to only occur in Chrome. Therefore, as a sure fallback for sorting, your solution is great. Thanks!